# change or force name of external files on the web when user download it in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, laravel-5, laravel-4

I was wonder if there is a way to force user requests to a route on the laravel app to get download an external file response from that route and if the name of the file is **name.type** it will download to the user system as **customname.type**

for example,

**this is the route in web.php**

```
Route::get('/testurl',function(){
   //then some have here by some magic it will force the user to download file on an external server on the web and change the original name of the file when a user downloads it
});
```

I know this is a challenging work to do.
ok, any expert guy and any of you guys can help me? and if it is done by some kind of technics outside of the framework(in my case laravel) I will be thankful to give me some advice. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can use

**Option 1:**

The streamDownload() function from laravel's [streamed downloads](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses)

```
  Route::get('/testurl',function(){
      return response()->streamDownload(function () {
        echo file_get_contents('google/images/125426ds2s.jpg');
    }, 'pic1.jpg');
  });
```

Keep in mind though, that this reads the entire file from the external source into memory, and therefore may not be a good idea, in which case use the second option:

**Option 2**

```
// Fetch the file from the external path
$contents = file_get_contents('google/images/125426ds2s.jpg');

// Save the contents to disc
Storage::disk('local')->put('125426ds2s.jpg', $contents);

// Get the file path within you local filesystem
$path = Storage::url('125426ds2s.jpg');

// Use laravel's download() helper to fetch the file
return response()->download($path, 'pic1.jpg', $headers);
```

**Option 3**

```
// redirect the user to the absolute url of the file
return \Redirect::to('google/images/125426ds2s.jpg');
```

Comment: tanks.but public_path() get the name of the file inside my server website in the public folder of the laravel project. but I want to user download files out side of my website (like an image URL in google) but with the name that I chose.let say that the user sends a get request to my website route like https://mywebsite/externaldownload   but it downloads a picture in google images with url:https://google/images/125426ds2s.jpg but with a name that I choose(instead of 1245.... it will be download to user disk as pic1.jpg) to download by the user.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include fetching the content and downloading on the client side

Comment: ok as I understand the streamDownload download the file to my server then create a link to it for my client.but I do not want to file download to my server because as the file size become biger like 5gig or more then user must wait to file first downloade to my site then can downloaded and it is so bad for user and trafic on my website.is there any way to change the name of file without first downloading it on my server?thank you

Comment: The first option does not save the file to disk, but rather saves it to memory, instead of saving on your disk, and removes it from memory once it is sent to the client. But you can only either save to your disk, like in the second option, or load the entire file in memory, like in the first option. The only other option I can see here is by pointing directly to the resource you want them to download, like in the third option I have provided.